Extending an integral in the complex plane
I'm having trouble with this exercise, I have to compute the integral:
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0}t^{z - 1}{\rm e}^{{\rm i}t}
\,{\rm d}t\quad
\mbox{where}\ \Re\left(z\right) > 1
$$
The book suggests to extend the path of integration into the complex plane and using the Residue Theorem but I don't know how to, the solution should be:
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0}t^{z - 1}{\rm e}^{{\rm i}t}
=
\Gamma\left(z\right){\rm e}^{-{\rm i}\pi z/2}
$$
Can anyone help me ?.

The result is  true for $ 0<z<1$. Nomally the integral diverges at $t=0$ or $t=\infty$

$$
{\rm e}^{{\rm i}t} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{\rm i}^{n}\cos\left(n\pi\right)
\,{\left(-t\right)^{n} \over n!}
$$
Then, the answer is given by
$$
\color{#44f}{\Gamma\left(z\right){\rm i}^{-z}\cos\left(\pi z\right)}
$$
This is the Ramanujan Master’s Theorem.

Why not $(-1)^n=e^{i\pi n}$?

@ТymaGaidash It is fine too.

Thank you, this was very helpful
